# Compare two Lists of CSVRecord objects

Tags: java-11, apache-commons-csv

I have two List. The CSVRecord is from the Apache commons-CSV library.
How do I compare them? The record in the two lists could be in a different order.
But I want to find out if the two lists are identical.
Is there a clean way to do it?

**My Thoughts:**
I can probably specify a comparator on the CSVRecord and sort according to that and then check the two lists for equality. I have not tested if this will work.